# ChessboardJS how to click to pick up and click again to drop off without the need to drag

Tags: javascript, chess, chessboard.js

I'm making some training tools using chessJS and chessboardJS currently I can only drag the piece from the source destination to the landing spot. ( if its not a legal move I have integrated the ChessboardJS code snippet that makes the piece snap back). I would like to know what additional piece of code I can add or what existing code I can combine so that I can just click the first piece that I want to move and then click the destination square and therefore won't be required to drag the piece.

I have tried using onMouseoverSquare and onDrop but had no success.

Thanks for your replies in advance.

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` at Question?